# Оперативная память и частоты

Tags: память, железо

- У меня ноутбук и там стоит 2 планки в материнке.
- Одна занята, другая свободна.
- Там стоит DDR4 2133mhz
- И могу ли я поставить туда DDR4 2666mhz? И будет ли работать?
- И еще это норм или надо именно 2133vs2133 2400vs2400 2666vs2666 3200vs3200
  Спасибо!

Comment: Какая марка и модель? Смотрите на сайте производителя совместимые модули. Вполне возможно, что работать будет, но на частоте самой медленной планки, то есть 2133 МГц в Вашем случае

Comment: Поставить можете, 2666 не будет. Быстрее чем самая медленная планка точно не будет работать.